# how to change extension of a file in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, file-extension

I downloaded a perl file from some webpage by opening it in my browser and saving it. But the saved file has a file name `xxx.pl.txt`.  How can I save it into a file with "pl" as its extension?

Also how to change a file's extension?

Can I do these in command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the command line:

```
rename xxx.pl.txt xxx.pl
```

Comment: More direct indeed.

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds. Well done.

Answer (score 4):

The extension is only a part of the file name. If you rename the file, you have only to take out the ".txt" extension, to have only pl.

I assume that you can see the full name, with extensions, according to what you said in the question. If not, you should change this option, [following these instructions](http://www.fileinfo.com/help/windows-show-extensions.html) (for XP, but it's [similar for Vista](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/show-or-hide-file-name-extensions) and 7).

Comment: I clicked at the file name, but the ext is not shown for me to change. It is only shown in it property.

Comment: @Tim you need to set the view to show extensions - Tools > Folder Options > View - uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types". This should be off by default as having it checked shows "virus.jpg.exe" as "virus.jpg". Having the former makes it less likely that you'll double click it.

Comment: Gnoupi: Keep in mind that the default is to *not* show file name extensions. Usually it's assumed that software does the right thing concerning file name extensions, so basically there would be little to no need for a normal user to ever mess with them (I only miss it once every second month or so as well).

Comment: @Johannes - I assumed that they were not hidden, because he described the full filename, with extension. I included instructions to show them, in case.

Comment: @Joey: it is this braindead decision (by Microsoft) which made e-mail attachments with .doc.exe extensions to flourish... Beside, it is a useful information (the type column is verbose) and I change such extensions almost daily (with the idiotic warning "Are you sure you want to change this extension?". Yes, I am sure!)

Answer (score 1):

```
rename originalname.ext newname.newext
```

Answer (score 0):

One useful thing, if you need to bulk rename extensions then you can do:

```
ren *.pl.txt *.pl
```

This will rename all .pl.txt files in directory to .pl files.